# How to use Selenium IDE to verify web service test form response

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a webservice with a test form:

[image]

I want to test the webservice and verify the response but the response opens in a new window. Is there any way using Selenium IDE to check the output in the newly opened window?

Update: the webservice test form does a POST with **target="_blank"** which results in the response being loaded into a new tab in Firefox. The response from the webservice is an xml document so many of the standard Selenium IDE commands that rely on a HTML Document will not work. I've found the [assertTextPresentXML](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/assertTextPresentXML) extension but I can't select the newly opened tab because it doesn't have a name, id, or title that I can access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectWindow` command and specify title of newly opened window (if this title differs from initial window):

```
selectWindow | title=New window title
```

Title can be retrieved from html>head>title. If it doesn't work you can try something like that:

```
getEval | selenium.browserbot.findElement('locator_of_invoke_button').target='my_window'
getEval | window.open("", "my_window")
click | locator_of_invoke_button
selectWindow | my_window
waitForElementPresent | locator_of_element_at_new_window
```

Comment: Thanks Aleh, this is a webservice request and the response is an xml document so no title. Plus the test form does a POST with **target="_blank"**.

Comment: @DavidClarke - you can specify **target="my_window"** instead of _blank, where `my_window` is the name you give to your new window. Please, try my second suggestion

Comment: Actually no, the form is generated by the webservice and cannot be modified. The only resolution I can think of is to create an html file that encapsulates the generated form and update it to open the response in a new frame in the same page maybe.